# Let $N=3^{1000}\times 2^{200009} +1$. Show that $5^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\equiv -1 \pmod{N}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

This is showing that 5 is a quadratic non-residue mod N but I don't get why this says it is prime.

The question also asks that you say that if p was prime divisor of N what the power of 2 dividing $ord_{p}(5)$ could mean and how to use that to conclude that all divisors p of N are $\equiv 1 \pmod{2^{2000009}}$. Not sure what the relevance of the the order is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are not sure why what says what is prime?

Comment: @fleablood I don't understand why it must be that N is prime. I'm not sure how to prove that it is

Comment: Is part of the problem N is prime?  If so, you should state that in your post somewhere.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768083/let-n-31000-cdot-22000009-1-if-5-fracn-12-1-pmod-n-the